# バックグラウンドでの定期的な処理について

Tags: swift, ios

swiftにてiOSアプリの作成を始めた初心者です。十数年前にc言語でPCのソフトを趣味で作っていた程度の経験値になります。

現在、バックグラウンドで定期的（5分間隔程度）にwebAPIにアクセスして、情報の更新があれば通知を行うようなアプリを作りたいと思っています。

自分なりに調べたところ、以下のような印象を受けました。

- バッテリーに負荷をかけないため、基本的にバックグラウンド処理は推奨されない
- background fetchは処理の間隔をiOSが決める、かつ毎回一定では無いので5分程度の間隔で処理したい場合は向かない
- Silent Push通知を利用して定期的にアプリを起こす？ただしPush通知実装にはサーバーの準備等、初心者には敷居がかなり高そう

時間を明確に指定してバックグラウンド処理を定期的に行うのは困難と考えた方が良いでしょうか？

ヒント等頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: 音楽アプリ・位置情報を利用したアプリの場合はバックグラウンド処理が可能です。その他のアプリでも実装する事は可能だったと思いますが、規約の関係でRejectされると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。　ご指摘の通り、なんらかの形で実装できてもリジェクトされてしまう可能性が高そうですね。悩ましいです。

Answer (score 2):

Objective-Cでの話ですが、
タイマー(NSTimer)と位置情報を連携する方法があります。

位置情報の取得はバックグラウンドでも動作が可能なのですが、
タイマーと連携させることで、
5分ごとに何らかの処理を実行することができるようになります。

以前書いたブログの記事が参考になるかと思います。
http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/location-nstimer/

位置情報を利用しない話だと思うので、
リジェクトされる可能性はあるかもしれませんが、試してみてはいかがでしょうか？
(Swiftにもタイマー処理はあるでしょうし。)

多少でも参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。以前からブログ拝見しておりました。
バックグラウンド処理を特例的に許可されている位置情報関連に偽装（？）する方法、でしょうか。大変勉強になります。
まだobjective-cからswiftにサクっと変換できる力が無いので、少しづつ読み解かせて頂きたいと思います。
しかしやはりいずれの方法でもリジェクトの懸念はついて回りそうですね。似たようなことをしたい人は多いと思うのですが・・・。PCの感覚とはやはり違いますね。

Comment: 記事を参考にさせていただき、swiftでBackground locationとNSTimerを組み合わせてバックグラウンド処理を定期的に実行することができました。ありがとうございました。
ちなみに初歩的なことなのですが、この処理は実機がスリープ状態でも実行され続けるものでしょうか？まだ実機で実際にテストする環境が無く、もし教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: うまく解決されたとのことで良かったです。

さて、お尋ねの件ですが、
実機がスリープ状態であってもバックグラウンドで動作をし続けます。
アプリが完全に停止している or 端末の電源OFFになっていなければ動作するはずです。
　
確か、一度タイマーが動けば、その後、位置情報が取得できなかったとしても、動作したと思います。
以前、`kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters `, `kCLDistanceFilterNone`
の設定で、同じ場所に滞在し続けていても問題ありませんでした。
ただし、
`pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically `を`NO(false)`にする必要はあったと思います。

Comment: 加藤様　ご回答ありがとうございます。スリープ状態でも動作するのですね。アクセプトされるかどうかは別にして、この方法で思っていたことが実現できそうです。pausesLocationUpdatesAutomaticallyについても注意したいと思います。

Answer (score 2):

background fetchでは間隔を制御できない＆最小間隔が長すぎるとのことでしたが、
background fetchの一回の処理の中でsleepを利用する方法はいかがでしょうか？

具体的には、background fetchを有効にした上で、
以下の様なコードをAppDelegateに実装します。
（例はObjective-Cですが、Swiftでも同じことができるはずです）

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler
{
    while (YES) {
        NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
        //定期処理

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5*60];
    }
}
```

実際に利用するには、
規約上問題のない実装なのか不明な点をクリアすることと、
次回のbackground fetchが走った際に前回のループを中断させる等の制御が必要になると思います。

取り急ぎ作成したサンプルアプリをシミュレータで実行してみたところ、
5分毎にNSLogで出力を行う処理を(初回を含めて)6回繰り返す
という動作までは確認できました。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
一度BackgroundFetchが呼ばれた際に自分でループを作ってしまうということですね。なるほど！
BackgroundFetchは30秒以内に処理を終了しないといけないのかと思っていたのですが、iOS Simulatorで動かしてみると問題無く動作しているように見えます。また、1度目のBackgroundFetchで動かしたループ中にさらにBackgroundFetchが来ると、1度目のループが終わってから次のループが始まるようです（BackgroundFetchが溜まっている）。
ご指摘の通りAppleからリジェックトされないか、バッテリーの消費はどうなのか、実機で問題なく動作するか等、気になるところは確認していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

自己レスですが、以下のようなコードを見つけました。

[Swift how to use NSTimer background? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27895060)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler({
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
        })
        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func update() {
        println("Something cool")
    }
}
```

iOS simulator上で実行してみると、確かにバックグラウンドでもprintlnが実行され続けます。
コメントとして”This apparently only runs for 3 minutes on iOS 7+.”との記載がありましたが、1時間経過後も動いたままでした。

不思議に思い、別途BackgroundFetchのperformFetchWithCompletionHandler中に同様にNSTimerを埋め込んでみたのですが、こちらも同様にバックグラウンドで処理が継続し続けます。

これもAppleにリジェクトされてしまうのかもしれませんが、長時間処理が許されていないはずの処理の中にNSTimerを埋め込んで一度呼ばれてしまいさえすれば、バックグラウンドでも処理が継続されてしまうのは少し不思議です。これが単純にiOS simulator上だからであって、実機では動かないのであれば納得なのですが・・・。

これらについて私の勘違いについての指摘やご知見ある方いればコメント頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score -1):

上記のバックグラウンドタスクとタイマーの方法を実機で試してみましたが、やはり3分程度でバックグラウンド処理が止まってしまいました。

Xcodeでデバッグしている間は、少なくとも3分以上は動いていました。