# Timerを利用したバックグラウンドでの位置情報の取得

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

【Tips】iOSで位置情報を取得する方法（Swift 3.0対応）
http://blog.koogawa.com/entry/2016/03/26/181906
バックグラウンドでの定期的な処理について
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/8513/18443

上記2サイトの処理をくっつけて「Timerを利用して、バックグラウンドでも位置情報を1秒ごとにprint出力するアプリ」をつくりたいのですが、アプリをバックグラウンドにすると、5秒ほどしてからprint出力がストップしてしまいます。
どこでミスが生じているのか、教えてください。

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var latTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lngTextField: UITextField!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager.delegate = self
            backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier!)
            })
            var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - CLLocationManager delegate
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .restricted, .denied:
            break
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            break
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let newLocation = locations.last,
            CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(newLocation.coordinate) else {
                self.latTextField.text = "Error"
                self.lngTextField.text = "Error"
                return
        }

        print("".appendingFormat("%.4f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude))
        self.latTextField.text = "".appendingFormat("%.4f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        self.lngTextField.text = "".appendingFormat("%.4f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    }

    func update(){
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結論から言うと、iOSで「Timerを利用して、バックグラウンドでも位置情報を1秒ごとにprint出力するアプリ」を作成することは不可能です。iOSの位置情報サービスの仕様に合わせてアプリの機能設計・仕様を見直してください。

---

リンクの2つめの記事ですが、大変実験的な結果を極めて限定的な条件で試された結果しか載っていません。Simulator以外では動くのか、(動いたとして)App Storeに承認されるのかなどの情報がありませんし、現実問題としてsimulatorではバックグラウンド動作が実機と異なるので、「simulatorではうまくいった」で終わっている記事はあてになりません。

リンク先のコードをSwift 3に置き換えて試してみました。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var backgroundTaskIdentifier: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        backgroundTaskIdentifier = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask {
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTaskIdentifier)
        }
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func update() {
        print(Date(), UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining)
    }
}
```

`update()`の出力中に`UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining`でバックグランド実行できる残り時間を表示させるようにしてみました。

実機(iOS 9.2)での実行結果はこちら:

```
...
2016-12-28 0午前0:05:53 +0000 1.79769313486232e+308
2016-12-28 0午前0:05:54 +0000 1.79769313486232e+308
(ここでHomeを押してバックグラウンドに移行)
2016-12-28 0午前0:05:55 +0000 179.780146666657
2016-12-28 0午前0:05:56 +0000 178.829380999989
2016-12-28 0午前0:05:57 +0000 177.805755624984
...
2016-12-28 0午前0:08:48 +0000 6.74223999999231
2016-12-28 0午前0:08:49 +0000 5.78680704167346
2016-12-28 0午前0:08:50 +0000 4.82001395832049
(ここで出力終了)
```

ご覧のようにおよそ180からカウントダウンが始まり、カウントダウンが0になる少し前に実行されなくなります。この方法によるバックグラウンド処理の延長は3分が限度、と言う情報が正しく実機での状況を表しているようです。

(時刻表示が変なのは環境設定によってはこうなっちゃうこともあると言う例だと思ってください。)

---

では、なぜあなたの処理は3分も保たずに「5秒ほど」で処理されなくなったのかというと原因はこちらでしょう。

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

`WhenInUse`と言うのは「使用中」のことで、「アプリの使用中は位置情報を取得する」と言う要求を出しているので、アプリがバックグランドに回る⇒使用中ではない⇒位置情報も取得できない、と言う状態なのだろうと思われます。

ここを

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

と置き換えれば、もう少し長く動き続ける可能性はありますが、こちらでテストした限り、それも実機がスタンバイ状態になるまでで、「最長でも3分、スタンバイ状態に入ればそれより早く終了」と言う形になりました。

そもそも`locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()`の処理は数秒かかることもあるという重い処理で、それを1秒ごとに呼び出すなんてことは**Appleの想定していないとんでもない使い方**と言うことになります。(一度起動してやると、あとはiOSが裏でバッテリー消費とかにも気をつけて位置の更新を検出してくれるのでそれを待つ、と言うのが想定された使い方。)

---

位置情報の取得というのは、「[iOSアプリケーション プログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)」にも記載されている「バックグラウンドでの動作が許可されている処理」の一つ([バックグランド実行](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1)参照)ですが、それも各処理をAppleの想定する使い方に従って処理する場合でのこと、Appleがレビュー時に「とんでもない使い方」を検知できるかどうかはわかりませんが、無理のある仕様で裏技的な解決策を求めるよりは、正攻法で「位置情報をバックグラウンドで取得する」方法を探し出して、その方法と制約のもとでアプリの仕様を見直した方が良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @sashihara さん、そちらの記事の方は、位置情報のバックグラウンドでの取得に関しては正攻法で処理しようとしているようです。ただし、「5分ごとに何らか‌​の処理を実行することができるようになりま‌​す」の部分が期待通りに動くかどうかについてはわからない、と言うのが正直なところです。また私が以前試したところでは「正攻法」のやり方でもバックグラウンドでの位地情報取得は必ずしも期待通りには動きませんでした。実機を外に持ち出して移動しながらでないと試せないので、数多く試したとは言えませんが、「1分毎に位置情報をサーバーに記録」を欠かさず確実に記録といった動作は不可能であろうと言うのが私がその時調べた時の感想です。(ちなみにリンク先記事中にある`location`プロパティは一番最近取得できた位置情報を返しますので、たとえタイマー処理が期待通りに動いても返されてくる位置情報は前回と全く同じ、と言う場合もあります。)該当記事も「そのうち本日、紹介した機能を使って実際にアプリを開発してみようと思います。」で閉められており、どの程度の環境で試されたのか不明です。試してみる価値はあるかもしれませんが、「これで動くはず」と判断するには根拠薄弱な記事だと言えるでしょう。

Comment: 元コメントが削除されているようなので、自己レスの形ですが、「[そちらの記事](http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/location-nstimer/)」のコードをSwift 3に置き換えて実機で試してみましたが、やはり「5‌​分ごとに何らか‌​の処理を実行することが‌​できるようになりま‌​す」の部分はバックグラウンドに移行したあとは実行されませんでした。絶対にできるはずがないという主張のための主張をするつもりはありませんが、とりあえずリンク先の記事(とそこから辿れる記事)からは(多少条件を緩めても)実地に動きそうなものは見当たりません。

Comment: すみません、元コメントを再掲します。→説明不足でした。正確には、1分毎に位置情報をサーバーに記録するGPSロガーのようなアプリをつくりたいのです。公開するつもりはないのでApp Storeの審査は考慮しなくてもよいのですが、最長でも3分のバックグラウンド実行が限界なのでしょうか。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/8457/18443 http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/location-nstimer/ このリンクの回答「位置情報の取得はバックグラウンドでも動作が可能なのですが、タイマーと連携させることで、5分ごとに何らかの処理を実行することができるようになります」も、やはり限定的な条件のもとでの結果、ということになるのでしょうか。